# Why this JQuery script can't modify the CSS settings of a selected element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am absolutely new to jQuery and I am going crazy trying to modify a script that do some operation on the DOM.

So this is my jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("thead.opening").click(function () {
            var tbodyElement =  $(this).next();

            $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function () {
                $(this).prev("thead.opening").toggleClass("active");
                $("thead.opening").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow.gif");
                $("thead.active").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow_down.gif");
            });

            tbodyElement.style.display = 'auto !important';
            return false;
        });
    });
```

And this is the section of HTML page on which it works:

```
<table class="standard-table-cls table-header-cls">
        <thead class="opening active">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <img class="imgAccordion" src="img/arrow_down.gif"/>
                Ricerca Flussi (la funzione e' consentita per flussi inferiori alle 300 fatture)
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="expanded">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100em;">
                    SHOW SOMETHING
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>

...........................................................
...........................................................
...........................................................


<table class="standard-table-cls table-header-cls">

    <thead class="opening">
        <tr>
            <th>
               <img class="imgAccordion" src="img/arrow.gif"/>
               Ricerca Fatture
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="expanded" style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100em;">
                 SHOW SOMETHING ELSE
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

<table>
```

As you can see in my code there is 2 different tables both having the same classes (**standard-table-cls table-header-cls**).

Ok, so the **$("thead.opening").click** is the clicked **thead** element having **class="opening"**, is it right or am I missing something?

Ok so now I want to set a specific CSS value to the **tbody** element related to the clicked **thead** element.

So, as you can see in the previous script, I added:

This line should select the **tbody** element related to the clicked **thead** element:

```
var tbodyElement =  $(this).next();
```

and at the end of the script I put this line that set the specific CSS settings:

```
tbodyElement.style.display = 'auto !important';
```

The problem is that this is performed but in the generated HTML I have not:

the **display: auto;** expected CSS but I still have:

```
<tbody class="expanded" style="display: block;">
```

that is the same value obtained before insert the previous 2 lines to my script.

Why it can't work? What am I missing? How can I fix this script to obtain the desired behavior that modify the display value of the tbody element related to the clicked thead?

Answer (score 1):

because `tbodyElement` is a jQuery object returned by the jQuery method `$(this).next()`, it has no `style` property, in jQuery it's the `css()` method that changes styles

```
tbodyElement.css('display', 'auto');
```

Note that javascript can't set `!important` rules, but it does change the inline styles that are attached to the element.

Also not that [there is no `auto` for the display style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), if you want to use the default for the element you do

```
tbodyElement.css('display', '');
```

assuming the display style isn't set in another style sheet

Comment: I tryied also this solotion but I still have that the tbody have a display: 'block' setted

Comment: It works for me in a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/q7tn41fy/), so something else must be going on. Something is setting the display property.

Answer (score 0):

Use css() jquery obj.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("thead.opening").click(function () {
                var tbodyElement =  $(this).next();

                $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function () {
                    $(this).prev("thead.opening").toggleClass("active");
                    $("thead.opening").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow.gif");
                    $("thead.active").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow_down.gif");
                });

                tbodyElement.css('display', 'auto');
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: I tryied also this solotion but I still have that the tbody have a display: 'block' setted

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("thead.opening").click(function () {

            $(this).next().slideToggle('slow', function () {
                $(this).prev("thead.opening").toggleClass("active");
                $("thead.opening").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow.gif");
                $("thead.active").find(".imgAccordion").attr("src", "img/arrow_down.gif");
            });

            $(this).next().css('display', 'auto');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: I still obtain the same issue :-(

Answer (score 0):

I see what your trying to do now, your trying to remove the style display prop to your default value. Don't use auto

Try this..

```
$(this).next().css('display', '');
```

Comment: I tryied but I still obtain the same issue...it remains display: 'block'